# Find command that excludes paths listed in a file

Tags: bash, find, path, xargs, gnu

I need to exclude a bunch of paths from a `find` command. For example:

```
find "$(pwd)" -not \( \
 -path "*/.git"\
 -o -path "*/.git/*"\
 -o -path "*/.vscode"\
 -o -path "*/.vscode/*"\
 -o -path "*/node_modules"\
 -o -path "*/node_modules/*"\
 -o -path "*/Image"\
 -o -path "*/Image/*"\
 -o -path "*/Rendered"\
 -o -path "*/Rendered/*"\
 -o -path "*/iNotebook"\
 -o -path "*/iNotebook/*"\
 -o -path "*/GeneratedTest"\
 -o -path "*/GeneratedTest/*"\
 -o -path "*/GeneratedOutput"\
 -o -path "*/GeneratedOutput/*"\
 -o -path "*/*_files" \) -type d
```

However, I want to read these paths from a text file instead of listing them all on the command-line. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Construct an array that you later use in your call to `find`.  The following script reads the newline-delimited path patterns from its standard input and calls `find`:

```
#!/bin/sh

set --

while IFS= read -r path; do
    set -- "$@" -o -path "$path"
done

shift   # remove initial "-o" from $@

find . -type d ! '(' "$@" ')'
```

You would run this with

```
./script.sh <paths.txt
```

where `paths.txt` might look like

```
*/.git
*/.git/*
*/.vscode
*/.vscode/*
*/node_modules
*/node_modules/*
*/Image
*/Image/*
*/Rendered
*/Rendered/*
*/iNotebook
*/iNotebook/*
*/GeneratedTest
*/GeneratedTest/*
*/GeneratedOutput
*/GeneratedOutput/*
*/*_files
```

Or, since your path patterns are all basically names of directories:

```
#!/bin/sh

set --

while IFS= read -r dirname; do
    set -- "$@" -o '(' -name "$dirname" -prune ')'
done

shift   # remove initial "-o" from $@

find . -type d ! '(' "$@" ')'
```

with the pattern file containing

```
.git
.vscode
node_modules
Image
Rendered
iNotebook
GeneratedTest
GeneratedOutput
*_files
```

This variant of the code would stop `find` from even descending into the directories matching the patterns in the file, whereas the first script (as well as your code) would test the `-path` patterns against everything in the excluded directories regardless of the fact that you're not interested in anything below those paths.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` and `find`’s `-exec` to filter files against a list of paths, either as regular expressions or fixed strings. Adapting your example, create a file named `paths` containing

```
/.git$
/.git/
/.vscode$
/.vscode/
/node_modules$
/node_modules/
/Image$
/Image/
/Rendered$
/Rendered/
/iNotebook$
/iNotebook/
/GeneratedTest$
/GeneratedTest/
/GeneratedOutput$
/GeneratedOutput/
/.*_files$
```

Then run

```
find /your/search/path -type d ! -exec sh -c "echo {} | grep -q -f paths" \; -print
```

This looks for directories under `/your/search/path`, and for each one it finds, uses `grep` to determine whether it matches a pattern in `paths`; if it doesn’t, it prints it. This is intended as a base for extension; if you only care about the paths of directories which don’t match the patterns in a file, *and* none of the paths cover multiple lines, you can post-process the output using a single `grep` invocation:

```
find /your/search/path -type d | grep -v -f paths
```

If you’re really not interested in certain paths at all (*i.e.* your patterns always match a directory name and then everything under that directory), you could make things simpler by pruning:

```
find /your/search/path -type d \( -exec sh -c "echo {} | grep -q -f paths" \; -prune -o -print \)
```

with the following contents in paths:

```
/.git$
/.vscode$
/node_modules$
/Image$
/Rendered$
/iNotebook$
/GeneratedTest$
/GeneratedOutput$
/.*_files$
```

Answer (score 1):

What can be done is to built up the command using `awk` and pass it to `find` as variable in a "wrapper" script or shell function

```
p=$( awk '{printf "-not -path %s ",$0}' "$1" )
find "$PWD"  $p -type d
```

And call it as `./find_wrapper.sh paths.txt`, where `path.txt` is the list of quoted paths.

```
'*/.git'
'*/.git/*'
'*/.vscode'
'*/.vscode/*'
'*/node_modules'
'*/node_modules/*'
'*/Image'
...
```

Why it's done this way ? The reason `awk` builts a one whole line is because there's no reason to do that in script - the `\` line continuations are for making the command look more organized, but functionally it doesn't give any advantage. `$p` is unquoted, since we actually want word splitting here. Otherwise `find` sees it as one giant string and not individual flags and arguments. As for single quotes, that's [to avoid glob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6495536/3701431) effect in double quotes.

Alternatively as pipeline

```
awk '{printf "-not -path %s ",$0}' "$1" | xargs -L 1  find "$PWD" -type d
```

Comment: The single quotes in the data would not stop the globbing patterns from expanding when you use `$p` unquoted.